# Swagger - IncludePatterns option not availbel in docket

Tags: java, swagger, springfox

I am trying to disable swagger in specific environment and I am able to do it by doing a .enable(false) in docket but the UI page still loads SWagger ui frame and displays null on the page. I would like to completely get rid of it but the include patterns option seems to no longer availble , any alternatives ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [selection api](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#springfox-swagger2-with-spring-mvc-and-spring-boot) in the docket (*see 4,5,6 & 7*).

```
 docket
    .select()
      .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any()) //<1>
      .paths(PathSelectors.ant("**/some-api-uri")) //<2>
      .build()
```

1. This is a predicate that allows you to filter based on `RequestHandler`s
2. This is a predicate based on path selection. It comes with some pre-selected ones like `ant` and `regex`. You can write your own predicates, but I suspect those will be sufficient for what you're looking for